# Click event on a post-AJAX drawn datatable not working from second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JQuery Datatable that is redrawn each time I click on a chart item.

I was using `.on()` to capture the click event, which was great in capturing the click events on all the rows, including those not currently in the DOM (i.e. not on page 1). However, although the click event is caught, I can't seem to access the data in the click event once the datatable was redrawn. Here is the code that is included in the AJAX `.success` function:

```
ajax_call()
    .success(function (data) {
        ...
        var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({...});
        ...
        $('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            var d = table.row( this ).data();
        });
    });
```

The error: `TypeError: d is undefined`

So I tried the `bind('click', ...)` catch:

```
$('#datatable tbody tr').bind( 'click', function () {
    var d = table.row( this ).data();
});
```

But this only catches click events from the rows in the DOM (i.e. 1st page).

So how should I catch the click events from all pages even if the datatable is redrawn in an AJAX `.success` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is to 'unbind' the .on() click event before re-initialising the table using .off() method. Multiple bound events on elements cause the data and bindings to be stacked.

So simply something like:

```
ajax_call().success(function (data) {
    ...
    $('#datatable tbody').off( 'click', 'tr');
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({...});
    ...
    $('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        var d = table.row( this ).data();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding your click event on the table container and in the event handler, check if the clicked target is the hotspot you are looking for:

```
$('#datatable_container').bind( 'click', function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if($target.prop("tagName") == "TR") {
       //Do something
       //...
    }
});
```

Since I can't see your source, I'm assuming it looks something like this:

```
<div id="datatable_container">
    <table id="datatable">...</table>
</div>
```

I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eTSQITBhro7ai9QKgdSJ?p=preview) showing what I mean. Hopefully it helps.